# Name chart title and axes automatically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I used this code to generate graph automatically over selected range of data but i also want to give it a title and names to axes automatically in one click for example i want to name x axis as subsection and y axis as count and i want to give a title to the chart as matrix graph how can i do that. Any help would really mean a lot Thanks in advance,sorry for any inconvenience

```
Sub create_embedded_chart()
Dim oChartObj As ChartObject

Set oChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=0, Left:=0, Width:=50, Height:=50)
oChartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Sheets("Tracedata").Range("A1:C45")

End Sub
```

[image: The graph]

Comment: Name its title: `oChartObj.Chart.HasTitle = True`, followed by ` oChartObj.Chart.chartTitle.text = "MyChart."`.  About axes naming it is a little more complicated in a comment. I will post an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next (updated) code:

```
Sub create_embedded_chart()
    Dim oChartObj As ChartObject

    Set oChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(top:=0, left:=0, width:=200, height:=200)
    oChartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Sheets("Tracedata").Range ("A1:C45")
    With oChartObj.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.text = "Matrix graph"
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .HasTitle = True
            With .AxisTitle
                .Caption = "Count"
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Italic = True
            End With
        End With
        With .Axes(xlCategory)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.text = "Subsection"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: The chart]

Comment: Working awesome!!Thanks made my day